# Problems with X11 and Inkscape

Tags: macos, mac, inkscape, x11-forwarding, truetype-fonts

How do i get X11 and Inkscape to work together? 
I cannot seem to locate X11 from Inkscape application when asked to find it. 
Is X11 a new terminal altogether. 
In simple, I need to know how to convert fonts from a png file to a rtf file and i was advised to use Inkscape which further required the usage and download of X11.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded & installed X11, a.k.a. XQuartz, from http://xquartz.macosforge.org/ yet? (It used to be bundled with OSX, but not any longer.) Once you download the `.dmg` file and install it from there, you should be good to go. If not, please provide more details.